# Changing font in Workbench (stand-alone) code editor

Tags: workbench

How do I change the font-size and the font set in the front-end code editor of Workbench 2.0 (stand alone)?

Answer (score 2):

Put [the tarlog](https://code.google.com/p/tarlog-plugins/downloads/list) jar file into your dropins or plugins folder of Workbech or Eclipe. Restart and enjoy font size changes by Ctr + and Ctrl -